# Equation in itemize

Tags: math-mode, itemize

What is the best way to reduce the space generated just before the second item?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1
  \item \begin{equation}\label{eq:1} x=1 \end{equation}
  \item Look at \eqref{eq:1}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

So that the item number is on the same line as the equation.
I know I can use inline math ($x=1$) but then I cannot reference the equation in the last item.

EDIT: Made a minimal example

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: I'd try using `\vpace{-2mm}`.

Comment: isn't it rather confusing to have both an item number and an equation number for the same thing? You could use inline math, then the `\label` would refer to the item number.

Comment: In my article, I actually reference the equation much later, so a simple reference to the item number is not enough.